# Layered navigation is showing in magento categories and subcategories

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

`First of all searched a lot but cant find any solution.`

My `layered navigation` block is not showing in any pages like `categories`,`sub categories`.
Using `template path hints` i saw the block is not getting rendered.

I set **is_anchor** to **YES** and also added filterable attributes in admin panel.

But no luck. Its not showing in frontend.

Can you guys please suggest.

Comment: It's been a while since I last fuzzed with this myself, but aren't you supposed to set **is_anchor** to **no**??

Comment: I already set is_anchor to YES and also added filterable attributes in admin panel.

Comment: What I meant to say was that setting it to 'yes' is most likely why there is no layered navigation. Try setting it to 'no' first ;)

Comment: @poepje not helping..same as previous

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself..my `list.phtml` had `2columns-right layout`.

Most of the `ajax layered navigation extension are based on 2columns-left`.They only support  2columns-left layout.

So i made it `2columns-left`.And now its coming.And the extension i used is **MD-AJAX FILTER**

### Another Option is

GO to the extension layout file and change the reference from `left` to `right`. For `their layerd navigation block`.